# What is the formula to calculate the surface area of a "crown" (stripe) of a sphere in spherical geometry?

Tags: matlab, spherical-coordinates, spheres, spherical-geometry

**EDIT: what I am looking for is called a "spherical zone", as pointed out by user Jean Marie**.

---

I need to calculate the area of a "crown", or "strip" of a sphere. Being new to the domain, I didn't find a better name for this. I think it corresponds to the surface area for two different, concentric steradians, but I could be wrong.

[image: Draft of the calculation of area of the surface area of a strip between two angles of a sphere]

Basically, I have a sphere with a phi and a theta angle. Let's slice the sphere by θ. From θ = 0 to a max value, I need to calculate in MATLAB the area of the "crown" between these two values. I can't find a way to do it...

A pseudocode approach would be this:

```
kmax = 120;
r = 50;
areas = []

for k=0 -> k=kmax
{ 
   areas[k] = calculate_area(k, k+1);
}

# Calculates the area of the strip on a sphere between two theta values
def calculate_area(k, k+1):
{

    area = r * sin(k) * (phi(k+1)-phi(k)) * (k+1-k)); # Just a guess
    return area;
}
```

I based my guess on [this](https://www.astronomyclub.xyz/celestial-sphere-2/) that I found, but it could be very wrong.

The final aim is to have a table of areas for every "strip" between k and k+1 for each angle in my theta range. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: One of the official names is "spherical zone"; see here where you will find (also) a [formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zone.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton @JeanMarie, these two are what I needed.